# Совет по дипломной работе

Tags: книги, cms, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте! Мне интересует темы для дипломного работы. Можно ли использовать готовые CMS движки для дипломного проекта? Как оценят комиссия? Какие новые веб технологий можно включить свой проект?

У меня тема веб портал "Литература"

Cпасибо!

Comment: >интересует темы для дипломного работы
>Как оценят комиссия?
>Какие новые веб технологий можно включить свой проект?

@bonus зачем так издеваться над русским языком? 

  Теперь что касается вопроса. Вообще у вас должен быть руководитель дипломного проекта, с которым можно обсудить тему работы. Вряд ли можно ответить на вопрос о том, как проект будет принят, не зная, где и на кого вы учитесь, не будучи знакомым с вашими преподавателями,их предпочтениями и критериями выставления оценки. Но вообще гораздо важнее темы проекта является уровень его исполнения.

Answer (score 2):

Я, конечно, не знаю, где вы учитесь, но:

1. Разработка веб-портала как диплом - очень странно
2. Основная вещь, на которую обращают внимание комиссии - новизна. Конкретнее - "а чем предложенное вами решение лучше уже существующих?"
3. В чем будет заключаться ваш дипломный проект "разработка веб-портала", если вы возьмете CMS, которая по сути и есть уже разработанный веб-портал?

Answer (score 1):

Просто сайтик в качестве дипломной работы это уровень "**удов.**"
Как вы хотите, что бы к вам отнеслись?

Я бы посоветовал не брать в голову CMS всякие, всё это лишь инструмент.

Сконцентрируйтесь на функциональности, например, предоставление книги по предпочтениям пользователя. Пусть пользователя ответит на ряд вопросов или оценит другие книжки или предоставит доступ к соц сети (оттуда вообще что угодно понять о человеке можно), а вы ему книжку относительно его предпочтений. Ещё круче если места из книжки выдернет, за которые пользователь её сразу полюбит и приобретает.

Вот когда разберётесь, что именно вы дадите искушенному клиенту, тогда и подавайте это в качестве дипломной работы. Т.е. тема не сам портал а *методика оценки предпочтений клиента на литературном Web портале*, она и будет ваши основным результатом.

Это уровень либо "**хор.**" либо "**отл.**" в зависимости от степени готовности.

Ещё не забывайте, про [научный метод](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4), т.е., если в общих чертах, поглядите, что уже есть, подумайте что можете доделать и сделайте так чтобы могли повторить.

Answer (score 1):

Указанная Вами тема не является как таковой. Это больше похоже на область исследования. А тема может звучать как "Улучшение качества предлагаемых услуг по реализации книг". На этом строится исследование, каким образом происходит реализация книг на данный момент. Предлагаются различные варианты решения возникшей проблемы, средства реализации решения и т.п. Вот в средствах реализации Вы, как раз, и можете применить какой-нибудь "движок".

Все зависит от того, какая у вас специальность. Если техническая и Вы учитесь, допустим, на программиста, то оценивать будут техническую сторону реализации. Если же гуманитарная специальность, то, более всего вероятно, что оценивать будут не саму реализацию, а идею и схему, а также практические результаты по улучшению качества.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы напишете свою CMS систему которая будет отличаться от других, причем эти отличия будут удобны для пользователей и разработчиков то тогда да.
Но обязательно должен быть анализ и других CMS систем на быстродействие, удобство и другие характеристики.
Сам знаю потому что сейчас занимаюсь этим, только это идет как курсовая работа)

Answer (score 0):

В вашей роботе должна быть новизна и актуальность. CMS может использоваться как средство.